# DBus Bluez5 CancelPairing()

Tags: python, dbus, bluez

When I Pair a device with a bt adapter a new debus object path of the form: `/org/bluez/${bt_device}/dev_${mac}` appears. Inspecting org.bluez.Device1 on this object there is a method called: CancelPairing() advertised.

Calling this method returns: `g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.DoesNotExist: Does Not Exist`

I try to pair devices and dissolve bt pairings in python using bluez5 dbus api through pydbus. Can You help me to achieve that? :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I'd like to accept and upvote your answers.

Comment: Comments have been converted to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bluez Device API documentation](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/device-api.txt) describes the `CancelPairing` method. It is not for removing an existing pairing that has already completed. It is used to:

> cancel a pairing operation initiated by the Pair method

The key word is "operation". That is, if you start a pairing and then decide not to complete it you can call `CancelPairing`.

For whatever reason, there is no Unpair DBUS API. To remove a pairing, the entire device should be removed with the `Adapter1.RemoveDevice` API as documented [here](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/adapter-api.txt)